# How to use chrome extension methods in my asp.net page?

Tags: google-chrome

I have page where RSS icon is present. I want that when user clicks on RSS icon it will check in chrome browser that, whether that RSS reader chrome extension is installed or not 
I am trying to achieve this by using chrome extension methods, mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#event-onConnect/).

I tried something like this but it is not working:

```js
var port = chrome.extension.connect("nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this API you need to be either an extension or a web application having the necessary permissions - normal web pages cannot access it. However, detecting whether an extension is installed in Chrome is still easy:

```html
<script src="chrome-extension://nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd/manifest.json"
        onload="alert('installed')" onerror="alert('not installed')"></script>
```

This uses the fact that the extension's `manifest.json` file is located under a predictable URL and that web pages are allowed to load this URL. Of course, this isn't an officially documented approach but rather a loophole and a privacy issue. So be prepared for it to stop working in some future Chrome version. At the moment it works however.

Comment: I My trying your above solution, I got stucked to one problem,
If i want to call function instead of calling alert the function is not get called.
Please help

Comment: Check the error messages. Maybe you are trying to call this function before it is defined?